# Как можно инвертировать цикл, чтобы он шел наоборот

Tags: java, циклы

Есть переменная

```
Collection<Socket> UsersMessage;
```

Которая получается от Карты

```
UsersMessage = onlineUsers.get(username);
```

Как можно инвертировать цикл, чтобы он сначала выводил последние значения, с помощью такого цикла?

```
            for (Socket test2222 : UsersMessage) {

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создать ArrayList используя копирующий конструктор
2. создать ListIterator с помощью этого ArrayList'a.(методы итератора вызывать вручную.)
3. ...
4. PROFIT